# static executable "cmake bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, linker, makefile, cmake, ld

So I'm trying to compile https://github.com/apngasm/apngasm (checkout url: https://github.com/apngasm/apngasm.git) to be a static executable for deployment on other systems.

However, I'm running into a snag with cmake.

I added the following to cli/CMakeLists.txt

```
SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a")
SET(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES OFF)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static")
```

And then the following to lib/CmakeLists.txt

```
SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a;.so")
SET(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES OFF)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static")
```

And changed the following lines from lib/CmakeLists.txt from

```
ADD_LIBRARY(apngasm SHARED
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/apngasm.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/apngframe.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/spec/specreader.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/spec/specwriter.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/spec/priv/specreaderimpl.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/spec/priv/specwriterimpl.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/listener/apngasmlistener.cpp
)
```

to

```
ADD_LIBRARY(apngasm STATIC
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/apngasm.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/apngframe.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/spec/specreader.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/spec/specwriter.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/spec/priv/specreaderimpl.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/spec/priv/specwriterimpl.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/listener/apngasmlistener.cpp
)
```

It compiles, but when I transfer the executable to the target system, it says:

```
bash: ./apngasm: /lib/ld64.so.1: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Where in there is the target architecture selected? What does `file` say about the binary you built?

Comment: @EtanReisner File outputs...

./cli/apngasm: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=385bb1ee142ddce3708b1e0dc74665009c289a7d, not stripped

Comment: And is that correct for the target system? Also I notice that isn't statically linked.

Comment: @EtanReisner The target system reports the following with uname -a. "Linux ex-std-node374.prod.rhcloud.com 2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jul 16 06:12:23 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux" if that helps. They're both 64-bit. I'm not sure why it's claiming to be dynamic when I set the -static flag.

Comment: Did it actually use `-static` when it compiled? Perhaps you didn't set it in the right place. I don't know either `apngasm` or `cmake` well enough to guess what you might have missed. What does `file` on a binary on the target system say? What about on `/lib/ld64.so.1`?

Comment: On the target system file reports "apngasm: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, not stripped." ldd says "/lib/ld64.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" and while ld64.so.1 does not exist, the file it seems linked to does. That file is a symlink to ld-212.so, which reports "/lib64/ld-2.12.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped" when file'd

Comment: I meant file on a native target binary not on the non-working binary. I don't understand your comment about `ld64.so.1` not existing. You just said you ran `ldd` on it. But this is beginning to sound like you might need to set up a cross-compilation environment for this to work though I am not at all sure about that.

Comment: This is very strange. I've filed an issue and he's working on making it. He knows his program more than me. I also managed to FINALLY get a version compiled from source on my target (I've been dealing with storage constraints and couldn't build boost)